# How can i edit the href of this specific class via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, href

I can figure out how i can change this href link via Javascript, can you guys help me?

The link i want to change is the above:

[Html Screenshot of the Link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNo2m.png)

```
<div class="view-project vp-global  font_rs0r6bbli"><a href="http://decatejo.pt/video-hp">SABER MAIS</a></div></div><div class="section">
```

Comment: You need to post the HTML in the question. Not the image.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal

I had edited with the code

Comment: I have added a answer. check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector('.view-project.vp-global.font_rs0r6bbli a').href` to set the `href` value of the `a` tag in that class. Use browser's inspect element on that link to check the `href` value being changed.

```js
var newHref = 'www.google.com';
document.querySelector('.view-project.vp-global.font_rs0r6bbli a').href = newHref;
```

```html
<div class="view-project vp-global font_rs0r6bbli"><a href="decatejo.pt/video-hp">SABER MAIS</a>
```

Comment: @JoãoApolinário glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch elements using the [query selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)..

```
let element = document.querySelector('.fp-tableCell .view-project.font_re0r6bbli a');

element.href="example.php";
```

but rather than fetching an element by its class I would recommend to use an specific id.

Comment: Thanks btw, but it doesn't seem to work, says:

(index):402 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null
    at (index):402